# C# Using property of instantation of an interface

Tags: c#

So let's say I have an base interface

```
public interface ISettings
{
   void setSettings();
}
```

The class

```
public abstract class Settings :ISettings
{
 public void setSettings()
  {
    //do something
  }
}

public class RealSettings : Settings
{
   public string ConnectionString {get;set;}
}
```

I want to use it this way:

```
//programstuff

private ISettings settings


settings = new RealSettings();
settings.setSettings();

logger.Debug(settings.ConnectionString);
```

Of course I can't use it this way. Because ConnectionString is not part of the interface.
What is the correct strategy to use now?

Comment: Just cast it to `realSettings`

Comment: Aside from anything else, now is a good time to learn about and start following .NET naming conventions, even for throwaway sample code.

Answer (score 1):

The concept behind the interface is you do *not* need implementation details. So probably your design is wrong to begin with.

I *assume* you want some kind of implementation which loads settings from configuration files and a set of interfaces to read settings from various categories i.e. the database connection strings.

You should just talk to `Interfaces` and not the implementation details. Therefore your approach to only put `ConnectionString` in the implementation is wrong. It needs to defined somewhere in the contracts.

So either:

- Create a property `ConnectionString` in the `ISettings`

Or, if you do not want this to be in the generic settings:

- Create an interface `IDatabaseSettings` and implement it at `Realsettings`. Then use `private IDatabaseSettings settings`.

If you are not able to change implementation details and if you always know it is `RealSettings`,

- use `(RealSettings)settings.ConnectionString`. Note this indicates bad design and it is best to avoid this kind of constructions as early as you can.

Comment: You're right, the abstract class was supposed to implement ISettings

Comment: You're right with your assumption. I'm doing some kind of implementation where others can implement and use their own settings. 
They should only implement the interface (which has more methods like loadSettings, validate, etc)

But the settings-manager will never know which kind of settingproperties the others might think off.

Comment: So the settingsmanager (A) will for instance list all made up settings from (B) which are configurable by (C). (B) Will use the configurated settings to handle stuff. IE B+C should get to ConnectionString while A acts as an intermediator to pass the settings along without having to know what they are.

Comment: I am not aware of any settingsmanager. However if you have working code you might want to post a question to 'Code Review' where people like to discuss different approaches to solve your design problem. This question is more like an Oo design problem instead of how to build a settings sytem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution for you.

```
    public interface ISettings
    {
        void SetSettings(); 
    }

    public interface IDataBaseSettings : ISettings
    {
         string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class DatabaseSettings : IDataBaseSettings
    {
        public void SetSettings()
        {
            //todo
        }

        public abstract string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

    public class SqlDataBaseSettings : DatabaseSettings
    {
        public override string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

 static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        IDataBaseSettings settings  = new SqlDataBaseSettings();
        settings.SetSettings();
        settings.ConnectionString = "Connection String";    
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You should first prefer which to use Interface or Abstract Class.Then I suggest you Creating a class that implements ISettings and then instantiate your interface over the class instantiation.

```
public interface ISettings
{
   void setSettings();
} 
    public class realSettings : ISettings
    {  
       public string settings;
       public string ConnectionString;
       public void setSettings(){
       // set the connectionString here the way you want.
       }
    }
ISetting set=new realSettings();
```

Comment: The `ConnectionString`-property is defined on neither the interface nor the abstract class, so this answer won´t help OP at all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I just tried to point the use of interface , can you see that ? We are not here to complete people's codes that can do the desired work .Sometimes we just keep it simple and show the main idea that helps solving the problem. Yes I agree with you there is no CONNECTIONSTRING PROPERTY here but anybody seeing the code can understand how to add it and apply basic use of interface .I think I explained why I omitted that CONNECTIONSTRING PROPERTY in an easy way  that anybody can understand the reason .